# eonasdan bootstrap datetimepicker minDate with exception for some past dates

Tags: jquery, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I want to disable past dates except for some(at least one), this is because my form doesn't allow picking past dates, but when I reload the form containing existing data I need to display that date in the date picker, but since I disable past dates, if the data being loaded is a past date, it just defaults to the date today.

```
$("#datepicker").datetimepicker({
 format: "YYYY-MM-DD, ddd",
 showClear: true,
 disabledDates: ["2020-06-03"],
 enabledDates: ["2020-06-04"],
 minDate: new Date(),
});
```

I've been experimenting with the 3 options `disabledDates`, `enabledDates`, and `minDate`, If i add a `minDate` it just disables past dates and ignore my `enabledDates`. `enabledDates` doesn't seem to work without `disabledDates`, I get an error saying "Uncaught Tried 31 times to find a valid date", is my option to just use `disabledDates` to disable past dates? what's the most optimal solution for creating an array consisting of the past dates so I can put it into `disabledDates`?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact scenario; the problem is that [en/disabled dates take precedence over each other and over min/maxDate](https://getdatepicker.com/4/Options/#endisableddates).

If you have a less open-ended range of eligible dates, you can just go all-in on `enabledDates`, as [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46790179).

My project included datetimepicker as a js file, so I wound up adding a new option, `alwaysEnabledDate`.

First time posting, so here's my best stab at explaining how I did it, entirely within `bootstrap-datetimepicker.js`:

1. Under `isValid` definition, after `targetMoment.isValid()` check and before checks on `disabledDates`, `enabledDates`, etc.:

```
if (options.alwaysEnabledDate && targetMoment.isSame(moment(options.alwaysEnabledDate), granularity)) {
    return true;
}
```

2. After the line beginning `$.fn.datetimepicker.defaults = {`, add: `alwaysEnabledDate: false,`, e.g.:

```
$.fn.datetimepicker.defaults = {
    alwaysEnabledDate: false,
    // ... existing code
}
```

3. Under the area with the heading "Public API functions" (where you see definitions for `picker.toggle`, `picker.show`, `picker.ignoreReadOnly`, etc.):

```
picker.alwaysEnabledDate = function (alwaysEnabledDate) {
    if (arguments.length === 0) {
        return options.alwaysEnabledDate ? options.alwaysEnabledDate.clone() : options.alwaysEnabledDate;
    }

    if ((typeof alwaysEnabledDate === 'boolean') && alwaysEnabledDate === false) {
        options.alwaysEnabledDate = false;
        update();
        return picker;
    }

    if (typeof alwaysEnabledDate === 'string') {
        if (alwaysEnabledDate === 'now' || alwaysEnabledDate === 'moment') {
            alwaysEnabledDate = getMoment();
        }
    }

    var parsedDate = parseInputDate(alwaysEnabledDate);

    if (!parsedDate.isValid()) {
        throw new TypeError('alwaysEnabledDate() Could not parse date parameter: ' + alwaysEnabledDate);
    }

    options.alwaysEnabledDate = parsedDate;
    update();
    return picker;
};
```

Given the above changes, your usage would then be:

```
$("#datepicker").datetimepicker({
 format: "YYYY-MM-DD, ddd",
 showClear: true,
 alwaysEnabledDate: '2020-06-04',
 minDate: new Date()
});
```

[In this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtgyB.png), I've initialized with a minDate of 6/12, and an `alwaysEnabledDate` of 6/3.

(Word of warning: I've only tested this approach with `day` granularity)